# 'PorterStemmer' object has no attribute 'stemWords'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
english_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
class StemmedTfidfVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer):
  def build_analyzer(self):
    analyzer = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
    return lambda doc: english_stemmer.stemWords(analyzer(doc))
```

I am new to python and I am having a problem when building my code. When I run the above code an error gets as given below:

> return lambda doc: english_stemmer.stemWords(analyzer(doc)) 
>   AttributeError: 'PorterStemmer' object has no attribute 'stemWords'

Comment: Your code looks unnecessary overcomplicated. What exactly do you want the built analyzer to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because there is no method 'stemWords' in PorterStemmer nltk implementation.

Here is a small example :

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
print(stemmer.stem('Running'))
```

> run

You can read more here:
http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html